# Optimal file size for a html5 background video stream with JWPlayer?

Tags: html, video, video-streaming, html5-video, jwplayer

On the homepage of my site I have a full screen html5 background video playing through JWPlayer.

My internet connection is so fast it loads instantly and plays perfectly.

So I'm wondering what would be a optimal file size, or how to test this?

Currently I've got a good quality 1 minute version at 10MB.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to emulate various web speeds, check out Charles Proxy (http://www.charlesproxy.com/). I'd hesitate to say there's an "optimal" size for a bg video. As always, smaller is probably better since it's faster. Check your analytics though and you can get a good feel for what your audience is like.

Comment: Thanks imjared - Charles proxy is great. Unfortunately for some reason it doesn't load the video.