# Make 50MB background video load faster on wordpress site

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to add a video to the background of a div that will autoplay on page load, but the size of the video is 50 MB. How can I optimize the video so that it loads faster? It's a Wordpress powered website.

I've added fast playback with video preload but it's not working as good.

```
<video id="video" preload="metadata" src="file.mp4" controls></video>

<script>
  video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
    if (video.buffered.length === 0) return;

    var bufferedSeconds = video.buffered.end(0) - video.buffered.start(0);
    console.log(bufferedSeconds + ' seconds of video are ready to play!');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Not a coding solution, but how many minutes has this video? Are you sure you can't render it with more compression?

Comment: Related: [What's the optimal file size for a looping HTML5 background?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31625629/1287812)

Comment: It's a 1 min 2 sec video mp4. But I don't want to reduce the Quality

Comment: It's possible to tweak the render settings until getting max quality with lowest size... Another possibility is to detect bandwidth and serve different quality videos